# Check changes before run synchronize

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Is there any way to check changes in database before running synchronize with MS Sync Framework?

I have a database with about 100 tables, 80% of these tables are not changed very often. I divided database into multiple scopes to handle the sync priority. Even though, there's no change in database, It takes a long time to finish synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you trace the Sync process to find out what's going on: [How to: Trace the Synchronization Process](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807160.aspx&ei=_gwEToNk6NOIAtKRscIN&usg=AFQjCNGvioi24tz2-tMhuT2EH3XwAqsxRA)

there is no specific API call in the Sync Framework SDK for simply checking a table has changed. most the API calls will do an actual change enumeration(read: query the base and tracking tables)

if you have large number of rows in your tables, you might want to set a retention period on the Sync Framework metadata to keep it small. see [How to: Clean Up Metadata for Collaborative Synchronization (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617373%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check out the Sync Framework Team Blog on [Synchronization Services for ADO .NET for Devices: Improving performance by skipping tables that don’t need synchronization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/03/02/synchronization-services-for-ado-net-for-devices-improving-performance-by-skipping-tables-that-don-t-need-synchronization.aspx)

Comment: the link above works for the offline providers (SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DbServerSyncProvider) where you can tweak which tables to include in particular sync session. Unfortunately, you can't do that with newer providers working scopes.